# Apache serve different app content if sub-folder like url is accessed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mod-rewrite, apache2

At this URL (http://www.seomoz.org/learn-seo/domain) the following is the *Subdomains or Sub-folders* section:

> 5. Subdomains or Sub-folders
>      Since search engines keep different metrics for domains than they do subdomains, it is recommended that webmasters place link worthy content like blogs in subfolders rather than subdomains. (i.e. www.example.com/blog/ rather than blog.example.com) The notable exceptions to this are language-specific websites. (i.e., en.example.com for the English version of the website).

So, here is the situation of mine to handle at the web-server (Apache2) level with `mod_rewrite`

I've a rails app running at `http://example.com`

Now I want to host a blog which is a PHP app WordPress at `http://blog.example.com`

What I want is if the user hits `http://example.com/blog` or any urls with `/blog/.....`, I want to show the content of `http://blog.example.com` or `http://blog.example.com/....` without changing the URL address.

I know that it should be handled at apache2 server level coz if it hits the url at `http://example.com/blog`, it will search for the match in the `routes.rb` file.

So, what would be the `mod_rewrite` rule to handle this using `.htaccess` file with apache2?

Answer (score 0):

You're actually better off using `mod_proxy` rather than `mod_rewrite`.  [See the ProxyPass docs here.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)